# Apparently my Intent does not get delivered

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an application that needs to start and stop activities.

So far we are OK with starting the Activity.

The problem comes when I try to stop the Activity.

This is the AlarmManager that broadcasts the intent to close the activity:

```
        Intent ftue = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);
        ftue.putExtra("finish", true);
        PendingIntent pftue = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, ftue, 0);
        Calendar calSet4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calSet4.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calSet4.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calSet4.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);
        calSet4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hftue);
        calSet4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mftue);
        calSet4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet4.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        //calSet.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet4.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pftue);
```

And in my Activty I have implemented a BroadcastReceiver that should shut down the Activty.

But without success...

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
IntentFilter f=new IntentFilter();
registerReceiver(receiver, f);
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
super.onPause();
}

BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("","intento ricevuto");
        if(intent.getBooleanExtra("finish",false))finish();

    }
};
```

Comment: What's your log cat? Is intento ricevuto?

Comment: Your `IntentFilter` is empty, which means it won't deliver any Broadcasts to your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make my comment an answer and expound on it.

If you use an empty `IntentFilter`, your activity won't ever receive any Intents broadcasted to it. However, if your broadcast intent specially reference a type of BroadcastReceiver, that would work.

So if you defined a class `MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` inside your `VideoActivity` and then formed the broadcast intent as `new Intent(context, VideoActivity.MyReceiver.class)` that *would* be delivered.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks that makes perfectly sense. Please what should I put in  the filter to get something delivered?

Comment: This should explain how to go about it. http://www.sohailaziz.com/2012/05/broadcast-receiver-two-ways-to.html

Comment: thank you very much, I get it, but please in this case what should I put in my filter?